# Android - Displaying and updating a MySQL database

Tags: php, android, mysql, eclipse

I have currently managed to create an android app which allows a user to register, and log in. The registered data is saved to the database, and the log in data is pulled from the database.

I now want to allow the user to make bookings from a list of classes (class table), which will be stored in a database. I need to display the class details to the user to allow them to select (with perhaps a checkbox) which class they wish to book.

After they have done this, the user will now be able to visit a screen which displays their bookings (userbooking table - joining table), and also allow them to "cancel" their booking, which will then update this table and remove their chosen booking from the table.

Does anyone know of any tutorial on a website/youtube which may assist me, or even personal knowledge with something such as this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would need a couple api calls.  One would authenticate your user and return a list of classes and details, so android can display them.  Another method would allow an authenticated user to create a booking from selected classes.  And a third would allow the user to modify or delete their bookings.

This is a textbook example of a CRUD api.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete, you will need some sort of authentication system for your users too.

http://www.myintervals.com/blog/2009/06/19/api-authentication-methodologies/